# Recursion theory from the standoint of category theory

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, soft-question, big-picture, computability-theory

It is (I believe) a very easy exercise to prove that the general recursive functions over the natural number object $N$ form a category.  But what sort of category is it? From the fact that one can prove the Recursion Theorem one might surmise that the category of general recusive functions over $N$ is cartesian closed, but what other category-theoretic properties does it have?

> Question 1:  Is it possible (for example) to characterize the category of general recursive functions over $N$ without having to deem specific functions as 'recursive' (as Kleene does in his papers)?

Furthermore, we now have types of 'recursiveness' over various structures, i.e. $\alpha$-recursive functions, $\beta$-recursive functions ($\alpha$-,$\beta$-recurision over the ordinals); Koepke and Koerwien's $\ast$-recursive functions over the ordinals (which characterize the constructible universe $L$), and Infinite Time Turing Machines; Sacks' $E$-recursion; Recursive functionals and quantifiers of finite type (Kleene); primitive recursive set functions and rudimentary set functions (Jensen, and others for studying the fine structure of $L$); abstract first-order computability (Moschovakis), to name but a few.

> Question 2: Can (or has) category theory (been able to) elucidate the structural interrelations between the various types of recursion?

Since I am certain that there is a subfield of category theory devoted to answering these types of questions (and probably already have answered some of these questions), I would be interested in obtaining a list of survey articles devoted to this subdiscipline, and (of course) the answers to the two questions I asked (the second can be answered from the survey articles by giving a few concrete examples).

Thanks in advance for any and all help given.

Comment: It may be that arithmetic universes are a candidate, or at least the arithmetic pretoposes of Maietti, which seem like the sort of structure engineered to allow a structural version of Gödel coding.

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  Would the class $Ord$ of all ordinals be deemed an 'arithmetic universe'?

Comment: An arithmetic universe is a kind of category. Just specifying the objects is insufficient. That said, I don't know if there is one with objects the ordinals.

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  (Silly question, maybe); If one considers the proper class of well-ordered sets and the morphisms between them as a category ($WO$), then is the proper class $Ord$ and its requisite morphisms the skeletal subcategory of $WO$ (sorry if I am not formulating the concept correctly--I just need advice on how to properly formulate the concept, thanks)?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. There is an isomorphism of well-ordered sets between a pair of ordinal iff the ordinals (I assume you have picked a construction, say the von Neumann one) are identical, if I'm not mistaken. I don't know how this helps your original question, though.

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  It helps by providing the beginnings of a category-theoretic characterization of inner models.  Since the category $WO$ of all well-ordered sets forms a model of $ZFC$ with the skeletal subcategory $Ord$ (i.e. the proper class  of all ordinals with its requisite morphisms), one can (seemingly) define an inner model of $ZFC$ as a large subcategory of $WO$ that has $Ord$ as its skeletal subcategory.  If this characterization is, in fact, correct, one should be able to classify the inner models of $ZFC$ by the proper class of morphisms that 'form' ( 'form' needs to be made

Comment: (cont.) precise) the sets of ordinals that make up the objects of the large subcategory in question.

Comment: This is nice, but makes use of more than just the category of sets structure, namely the additional structure afforded by the specific construction of ordinals. One can make Set into what is known as an M-category (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/M-category#definitions), with tight morphisms those functions that preserve the well-founded tree structure given by $\in$, and loose morphisms the ordinary functions of sets. I don't know if one can identify the von Neumann ordinals among all sets using purely category-theoretic means from this M-category. Certainly, starting from ETCS one can't do it.

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  Can one define the notion of 'transitive set' in $ETCS$?  If so, how?

Comment: Sets as objects of the category of sets as axiomatised structurally do not have other sets as elements. You can talk about accessible pointed graphs, but this is extra structure. You are recovering the Mitchell-Osius-Cole construction of a model of Zermelo set theory from a model of ETCS, in this line of reasoning. Note that an inner model _shouldn't necessarily_ give a full subcategory, because there could be fewer functions in the inner model. This makes things tricky, as the inclusion functor doesn't respect inner homs or power sets. And so on.

Comment: That said, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+set#formalization_in_structural_set_theory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for but I think that the following paper may provide an answer to your question 1:

J. Robin B. Cockett, Pieter J. W. Hofstra:
Introduction to Turing categories. Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 156(2-3): 183-209 (2008)

It gives a categorical axiomatization of computability in arbitrary categories (not just sets and partial maps).  The basic notion is that of *Turing category* which, in a nutshell, is:

- a *restriction category*, that is, a "category of partial maps": for every $f:A\to B$, there is a monic $\overline f:A\to A$ which morally represents the domain of $f$ as a "partial identity map" (subject to some axioms); *total maps* are arrows $f:A\to B$ such that $\overline f=\mathrm{id}_A$;
- it has a notion of product that interacts well with the partiality structure;
- it has a *Turing object*, which is morally an "object of programs"; technically, it is a sort of "universal internal hom": it is an object $T$ together with a map $\mathrm{eval}_{A,B}:T\times A\to B$ for every objects $A,B$, such that, for all $f:\Gamma\times A\to B$, there is a total map $f^\bullet:\Gamma\to T$ such that
  $$\mathrm{eval}_{A,B}\circ (f^\bullet\times \mathrm{id}_A)=f.$$
  The map $f^\bullet$ is called a *code* of $f$ and is not required to be unique (morally, it is a program parametric in $\Gamma$).

The category whose objects are powers of $\mathbb N$ and whose arrows are partial recursive functions is the prototypical example of Turing category ($\mathbb N$ is a Turing object, seen as the set of codes of recursive functions).

Apart from the above paper, there is also [this survey](http://cs.ioc.ee/ewscs/2010/cockett/estonia-notes.pdf) by Robin Cockett in which he shows how some of the basic theorems of computability theory may be proved in the framework of Turing categories.

By the way, Turing categories are not the only proposal to axiomatize computability categorically; Cockett and Hofstra mention previous work in the introduction to their paper, which you may also find of interest.

As far as your question 2 is concerned, I don't think Cockett and coauthors studied the extensions of recursive functions that you mention.  However, they did turn their attention to sub-recursive settings (i.e., complexity theory), and found out that there are Turing categories whose total maps correspond to well-known complexity classes (polynomial time, logspace).  If I am not mistaken, this is done in the following two papers:

Robin Cockett, Joaquín Díaz-Boïls, Jonathan Gallagher, Pavel Hrubes:
Timed Sets, Functional Complexity, and Computability. Electr. Notes Theor. Comput. Sci. 286: 117-137 (2012)

J. Robin B. Cockett, Pieter J. W. Hofstra, Pavel Hrubes:
Total Maps of Turing Categories. Electr. Notes Theor. Comput. Sci. 308: 129-146 (2014)

Comment: Actually, if you read the Introduction to the Cockett-Hofstra paper you mention, they state that the Uniformly Reflexive Structures of Wagner and Strong; and Moschovakis' work on abstract first-order computability and his work on (pre)computation theories..."single out a class of well-behaved combinatory structures and prove the elementary recursion theoretic results for the objects in this class...in hindsight, this may be seen as the study of the class of decidable partial combinatory algebras in the category of sets; as such, they are examples of the kind of structures

Comment: (cont.)  we shall be considering in this paper".  This shows (and Cockett discusses recursion categories in the survey article you provide in your answer) that Turing categories probably relate (in some sense) all the variants of 'recursiveness' I mention in my question (how, and how not, have the makings of a nice research programme....).   Thanks.

Comment: Good to know!  I'm glad you found the paper interesting.

Comment: Conjecture:  The category $Set$ has a unique large subcategory that is a Turing category, and that is the constructible universe $L$.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Why on earth should that be true? Just because $L$ and computability have a certain affinity?